# Clearing cookie after sendbeacon on window.unload event in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, http

So i have the following requirement when the browser is closed or when tab is closed:

1. Send a post request to my server(should be reliable and send request every time).
2. After sending the request, delete the cookies using my synchronous function.

now, i have the following code:

```
 function deleteCookie(){
   // code to delete the cookie
 }

 window.addEventListener('unload', ev => {
     navigator.sendBeacon(url,body)
     deleteCookie()
})
```

What is happening right now is, the browser is deleting the cookies before sending the request.
I need the cookies in my request. Any help would be appreciated.

In IE i don't have this issue as I can send synchronous requests in unload event.

Comment: Can you have the server unset the cookie with a cookie header instead?  I don't know that the browser will actually wait for `fetch` calls in an unload listener.

Comment: _“In IE i don't have this issue as I can send synchronous requests in unload event.”_ - that’s what I would call “a problem that the IE developers must fix”, haha.

Comment: _Why_ does the cookie need to be removed? Maybe the actual problem can be solved in a different way, by declaring it invalid on the server side, or something like that.

Comment: @CBroe IE it's really a mess hahahahahahahahaha

Comment: @CBroe I need to clear session cookies so the user will be prompted to login again when the tab closes.

Comment: Can you just destroy the session on the server side? Then the user would automatically be asked to login again on their next visit.

Comment: the navigator.sendbeacon is still very unreliable. It is sending the request everytime when i close a tab. But when the browser closes, 1 in 5-6 requests is not getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

sendBeacon is asynchronous, and don't wait for a return or a promise.
I think you should use fetch().

```
function deleteCookie(){
   // code to delete the cookie
 }


async function doSomething() {
navigator.sendBeacon(url,body)
     deleteCookie()
}

window.addEventListener("unload", () => doSomething(), false);
```

Comment: Are you sure that a `unload` event callback will actually wait for a fetch to complete before continuing?

Comment: .then is not getting called.

Comment: I don't expected this. Try using async `window.addEventListener("unload", async () => { //... code }, false);`

Comment: This also is working the same way. Fetch is also asynchronous and i tried with the keepAlive set to true.
Async unload and awaiting the fetch sends out the request but it is not clearing the cookies.